# Error during deleting files from File Service. Checkin will be aborted

Tags: testing, tosca, testautomationfx

I recently started working with the Tosca Automation Tool.
At the moment I'm still Testing each TestCase for itsself, not using the Execution List.
As soon as I try to "Checkin All", im getting the error message stated above.

Apparently there is a Problem with the File-Service, it tries to delete the last log, but can not find a file that is stated there. Even if I go to the directory stated in the log and create a file with the name given I'm still getting the same error Code.

Can't find anything online yet so I hope somebody here might help me.

Big Thanks in advance

Best regards